# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Not Found at Gaxios.<anonymous> when trying to add event to Google Calendar

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api, google-workspace

I'm trying to create a new event in google calendar and send the Hangout meets link to the user. I'm using GSuite delegated credentials and it's not easy to find documentation on this in Node js. I found this [post](https://hackernoon.com/my-journey-integrating-google-calendar-g-suite-in-node-62fbc8596455) how to list events and it's working fine. But when I use it to create event I get this error:

**UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Not Found**
    at Gaxios. (C:\optt\node_modules\gaxios\build\src\gaxios.js:73:27)
    at Generator.next ()
    at fulfilled (C:\optt\node_modules\gaxios\build\src\gaxios.js:16:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:23328) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:23328) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Here is my code:

```
const google = require("googleapis").google;

const calendar = google.calendar("v3");
var event = {
'summary': 'Google I/O 2015',
'location': '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
'description': 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
'start': {
  'dateTime': '2020-06-12T09:00:00-07:00',
  'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
},
'end': {
  'dateTime': '2020-06-12T12:00:00-07:00',
  'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
},

'conferenceData': {
    'createRequest': {
      'conferenceSolutionKey': {
        'type': 'hangoutsMeet'
        },
     'requestId': 'iyfuted65e3ers'

    }
  },

'attendees': [
  {'email': 'hjg@example.com'},
  {'email': 'sbrin@example.com'},
],
'reminders': {
  'useDefault': false,
  'overrides': [
    {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60},
    {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10},
  ],
 },
};

(async function () {
 const scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'];
 const keyFile = './credentials.json';   
 const client = await google.auth.getClient({
     keyFile,
     scopes,
 });

// Delegated Credential
client.subject = 'example@test.com'; 

const res = await calendar.calendarList.insert({
    auth: client,
    calendarId: 'primary',
    conferenceDataVersion: 1,
    resource: event,
});

//listEvents();
console.log(JSON.stringify(res.data));
})();
```

Comment: Which one is the line throwing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was inserting the data wrong. Here is the write code if anyone needed:

```
const google = require("googleapis").google;

const calendar = google.calendar("v3");
var event = {
'summary': 'Google I/O 2015',
'location': '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
'description': 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
'start': {
  'dateTime': '2020-06-12T09:00:00-07:00',
  'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
},
'end': {
  'dateTime': '2020-06-12T12:00:00-07:00',
  'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
},
'conferenceData': {
   'createRequest': {
     'conferenceSolutionKey': {
       'type': 'hangoutsMeet'
       },
    'requestId': 'iyfuted65e3ers'

   }
 }, 
'attendees': [
{'email': 'hjg@example.com'},
{'email': 'sbrin@example.com'},
],
'reminders': {
'useDefault': false,
'overrides': [
   {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60},
   {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10},
  ],
 },
};
(async function () {
  const scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'];
  const keyFile = './credentials.json';   
  const client = await google.auth.getClient({
      keyFile,
      scopes,
 });

 // Delegated Credential
 client.subject = 'example@test.com'; 
 const res = await calendar.calendar.events.insert({
 auth: client,
 calendarId: 'primary',
 conferenceDataVersion: 1,
 resource: event,
});
//CreateEvents();
 console.log(JSON.stringify(res.data.hangoutLink));
 })();
```